Не могу настроить одностороннюю видео связь на pjsip
Я использую проект pjsip 2.14 на Orange Pi Zero 3 с Ubuntu 22.04 server. К Orange Pi подключена USB видеокамера. Она настроена как камера по умолчанию. Orange Pi не имеет экрана для отображения какой-либо информации. Доступ к ней производится по ssh с другого компьютера. Для связи использую стандартный пример pjsua. Сейчас я могу делать видео звонок от Orange Pi абоненту, но при этом абонент не получает видеопоток. В логе pjsip я могу видеть такие сообщения:
15:27:05.507            pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 state changed to CONNECTING
15:27:05.507            pjsua_app.c  .....--------------
15:27:05.507      inv0xaaab036a7f28  ....SDP negotiation done: Success
15:27:05.507          pjsua_media.c  .....Call 0: updating media..
15:27:05.507          pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:0 is destroyed
15:27:05.507      udp0xaaab0366bb40  ......UDP media transport started
15:27:05.507            pjsua_aud.c  ......Audio channel update..
15:27:05.508      udp0xaaab0366bb40  .......UDP media transport attached
15:27:05.508     strm0xffffb4013768  .......Encoder stream started
15:27:05.508     strm0xffffb4013768  .......Decoder stream started
15:27:05.508          pjsua_media.c  ......Audio updated, stream #0: PCMU (sendrecv)
15:27:05.508          pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
15:27:05.508      udp0xaaab036a92b0  ......UDP media transport started
15:27:05.508            pjsua_vid.c  ......Video channel update..
15:27:05.515      udp0xaaab036a92b0  .......UDP media transport attached
15:27:05.516   vstenc0xffffb4019dc8  .......Encoder stream started
15:27:05.516   vstdec0xffffb4019dc8  .......Decoder stream started
15:27:05.516            pjsua_vid.c  .......Setting up RX..
15:27:05.516            pjsua_vid.c  ........Creating video window: type=stream, cap_id=-1, rend_id=-2
15:27:05.516            pjsua_vid.c  .........Window 0: destroying..
15:27:05.516          pjsua_media.c  ......pjsua_vid_channel_update() failed for call_id 0 media 1: Unable to find default video device (PJMEDIA_EVID_NODEFDEV)
15:27:05.516            pjsua_vid.c  .......Stopping video stream..
15:27:05.516           vid_stream.c  ........Destroy request on vstrm0xffffb4019dc8..
15:27:05.516      udp0xaaab036a92b0  ........UDP media transport detached
15:27:05.516           vid_stream.c  ........Destroying vstrm0xffffb4019dc8..
15:27:05.517          pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
15:27:05.517     srtp0xaaab036b12d0  ......Destroying SRTP transport
15:27:05.518      udp0xaaab036a92b0  ......UDP media transport destroyed
15:27:05.518     srtp0xaaab036b12d0  ......SRTP transport destroyed
15:27:05.518          pjsua_media.c  ......Error updating media call00:1: Unable to find default video device (PJMEDIA_EVID_NODEFDEV)

...

15:27:05.541      inv0xaaab036a7f28  ....SDP negotiation done: Success
15:27:05.541          pjsua_media.c  .....Call 0: updating media..
15:27:05.541          pjsua_media.c  ......Call 0: stream #0 (audio) unchanged.
15:27:05.541          pjsua_media.c  ......Audio updated, stream #0: PCMU (sendrecv)
15:27:05.541          pjsua_media.c  ......pjmedia_vid_stream_info_from_sdp() failed for call_id 0 media 1: Unsupported address family (PJ_EAFNOTSUP)
15:27:05.541          pjsua_media.c  .......Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
15:27:05.542          pjsua_media.c  ......Error updating media call00:1: Unsupported address family (PJ_EAFNOTSUP)
15:27:05.542            pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 media 0 [type=audio], status is Active
15:27:05.542            pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf connect: 3 --> 0
15:27:05.542            pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf connect: 0 --> 3
15:27:05.542            pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 media 1 [type=video], status is Error

Только я не пойму - ошибка Unable to find default video device относится к видеокамере или к устройству вывода видео информации (дисплею)?
Подскажите, в чём проблема, почему не удаётся настроить одностороннюю видеосвязь используя pjsua?

Сип обычно настроен так что видео включается когда оба абонента включают его.

Попробуй с виртуальным X сервером.

@eri, спасибо, попробую
